# How to get Sql execution plan from a Oracle package runned with function with parameters using SQL*Plus?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I need to sniff out a SQL execution plan of a Oracle package.

The SQL*Plus code to run this package looks like this:

```
VARIABLE RC REFCURSOR
EXEC :RC :=PACKAGENAME.GETREPORTDATA('12_300',1999,2014,'246246',NULL)
PRINT RC
```

I have to do it using SQL*Plus, cause It's a part of a Jenkins job, and I need to save the output to a file, for further comparision purposes.

I have been informed about a method to do this, it looks like this:

```
select 
        sqlplan.operation, 
        sqlplan.options, 
        sqlplan.object_name, 
        sqlplan.cost, 
        sqlplan.depth   
  from v$sqlarea sqlarea, 
       v$session sesion, 
       v$sql_plan sqlplan
where sesion.sql_hash_value = sqlarea.hash_value
   and sesion.sql_address    = sqlarea.address
   and sqlarea.plan_hash_value = sqlplan.plan_hash_value
   and sesion.username = 'USERNAME' order by sqlplan.depth;
```

But all I get from this code is

```
       v$sql_plan sqlplan
       *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The other thing I found out about is `EXPLAIN PLAN` command but it is not working for me, or I'm using it wrong.

To be honest, I just don't know where to start with this...

Any information will be honestly appreciated by me :)

Comment: have you tried putting a sys. in front of the views?

Comment: or you could trace the session and use tkprof to get the plans for every statement

Comment: Another option is to check get the `sql_id` of the executed statement through `v$session` and then use `dbms_xplan.display_cursor()` to get the stored execution plan.

Comment: As what user is all of this run ? - Error message 00942 should be read as "table or view does not exist for the current user, or user specified, or table read permissions are lacking". Often, typing mistakes are the cause, or the name is not what you though (I don't know, this one looks valid). Or, user issues of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on Oracle trace and then go through the tracefile

```
-- All versions.
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET sql_trace=TRUE;
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET sql_trace=FALSE;

SQL> EXEC DBMS_SESSION.set_sql_trace(sql_trace => TRUE);
SQL> EXEC DBMS_SESSION.set_sql_trace(sql_trace => FALSE);

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context forever, level 8';
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context off';

SQL> EXEC DBMS_SYSTEM.set_sql_trace_in_session(sid=>123, serial#=>1234, sql_trace=>TRUE);
SQL> EXEC DBMS_SYSTEM.set_sql_trace_in_session(sid=>123, serial#=>1234, sql_trace=>FALSE);

SQL> EXEC DBMS_SYSTEM.set_ev(si=>123, se=>1234, ev=>10046, le=>8, nm=>' ');
SQL> EXEC DBMS_SYSTEM.set_ev(si=>123, se=>1234, ev=>10046, le=>0, nm=>' ');

-- Available from SQL*Plus since 8i (commandline utility prior to this.
SQL> CONN sys/password AS SYSDBA;  -- User must have SYSDBA.
SQL> ORADEBUG SETMYPID;            -- Debug current session.
SQL> ORADEBUG SETOSPID 1234;       -- Debug session with the specified OS process.
SQL> ORADEBUG SETORAPID 123456;    -- Debug session with the specified Oracle process ID.

SQL> ORADEBUG EVENT 10046 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 12;
SQL> ORADEBUG TRACEFILE_NAME;      -- Display the current trace file.
SQL> ORADEBUG EVENT 10046 TRACE NAME CONTEXT OFF;

-- All versions, requires DBMS_SUPPORT package to be loaded.
SQL> EXEC DBMS_SUPPORT.start_trace(waits=>TRUE, binds=>FALSE);
SQL> EXEC DBMS_SUPPORT.stop_trace;

SQL> EXEC DBMS_SUPPORT.start_trace_in_session(sid=>123, serial=>1234, waits=>TRUE, binds=>FALSE);
SQL> EXEC DBMS_SUPPORT.stop_trace_in_session(sid=>123, serial=>1234);
```

0 - No trace. Like switching sql_trace off.
2 - The equivalent of regular sql_trace.
4 - The same as 2, but with the addition of bind variable values.
8 - The same as 2, but with the addition of wait events.
12 - The same as 2, but with both bind variable values and wait events.

Then you would use the oracle utility "tkprof" to format the trace to a more readable version.